# Welcome to macOS High Sierra message keeps appearing

Tags: high-sierra

At every start I get the message "Welcome to macOS High Sierra". Whatever I click - Show/Later(remind me, don't remind me) it appears on the next start.

I was using the beta version so it could be the cause of the problem still I don't see any solution in the internet and it gets annoying. Can anyone help?

Comment: I kept getting the same message and I wasn't on the beta.  The only way I could get rid of it was to go thru it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: That's always been the case - all the options are 'not now', but not now means later... you gotta do it some time...

Comment: @fsb, I think I did click on 'Show'. Whether I have exactly scrolled to the end, I can't remember. It seems that this appears only once a day, so I'll have to wait till tomorrow to try again...

Comment: If that addresses your question, please let me know.  i'll add it as an answer and hopefully it will help others, too.

Comment: I have clicked many times on 'Show' after a startup, the dialog disappears but nothing shows and next time the dialog is back.

Comment: @fsb, I can confirm that I have the same experience as Matariki, if I click show nothing happens, on the next start notification is shown again, so your suggestion wasn't a solution.

Comment: All I can tell you is I'm not on the beta and I clicked 'Show' and went thru it.  After that, I don't see the message anymore.  That's why I added the info as a comment and not an Answer.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue with High Sierra 13.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in High Sierra 13.1